# An equivalent to If contains using SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a program that needs to check if a value exists in column 1 of my database, if not then add it or if it does then add 1 to the value in column 2.

Currently the program only adds each value to the database and I don't know how to do the next part, it should do something like:

```
if column 1 contains (textbox)
column 2 = column 2 + 1

else column 1 doesnt contain (textbox)
add to column 1
```

I'm only just learning C# and this is pretty much the first SQL i've had to do, so please keep any answers simple.

This is part of the code that currently works.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Tags"].NewRow();
dRow[0] = txtSplittext.Text;
dRow[1] = 1;
ds1.Tables["Tags"].Rows.Add(dRow);
MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
inc = MaxRows - 1;
da.Update(ds1, "Tags");
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Rather than tell us what the program does, it might be more helpful if you told us, conceptually, what you're trying to achieve.  We might know of more straightforward ways to approach it.  But I applaud you for trying what you've done so far, as many new posters do a very poor job of showing any code at all.  You're already ahead of the game.

Comment: Overall the program is meant to read in a tweet and translate any text speak found, this part is meant to records hashtags and how many times they've been used.

Comment: For the else clause, what do you want to add to column 1?

Comment: The contents of the textbox, and set column 2 to 1

Answer (score 0):

You want a basic update statement in SQL:

```
update table
    set column_2 = (case when charindex([textbox], column_1) > 0 then column_2 + 1 else column_2 end),
    set column_1 = (case when charindex([textbox], column_1) = 0 then column_1 + 1 else column_1 end)
```

(You could alternatively use the SQL "like" command, which should work in all dialects.  I've chosen a Microsoft equivalent that is likely to be more efficient.)

In the above SQL, [textbox] represents the value in the text box.  You can insert it into such a query either using dynamic SQL or as a parameter.

I am also assuming that you only want to do this for one row.  If so, then this needs a where clause to identify the row (preferably with a primary key).